# Make nested module public in Rust

Tags: module, rust, rust-cargo

I'm starting a project to learn Rust and I fail at the most basic things, like setting up a proper module structure. My code looks like this:

```
// src/theorem/math.rs
pub mod theorem {
    pub mod math {
        use std::ops::{Add, Sub};

        pub struct Point {
            x: i32,
            y: i32,
        }

        impl Add for Point {
            // Omitted...
        }
    }

    pub use math::{Point};
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use theorem::math::{Point};

    #[test]
    fn add_point() {
        let v1 = Point { x: 1, y: 1 };
        let v2 = Point { x: 2, y: 2 };
        assert_eq!(v1 + v1, v2);
    }
}
```

I tried `pub use`, and I tried to write `pub` in front of everything, everywhere, but all I get is the message

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `math::Point`
  --> src/theorem/math.rs:28:20
   |
28 |     pub use math::{Point};
   |                    ^^^^^ no `Point` in `math`
```

Which is a nice insight but does not help me. I read through the docs but there are no real examples for this case, but... it must be possible, right?

I have also tried to have a proper directory structure like `src/theorem/math/point.rs` but that did not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What compiler version do you use? [Since version 1.13](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/36289), the error message looks like this:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `math::Point`
  --> <anon>:16:20
   |
16 |     pub use math::{Point};
   |                    ^^^^^ Did you mean `self::math`?
```

And `pub use self::math::{Point};` is in fact the solution to your question! When you `use` a path, this path is *always* an absolute path. This means it is interpreted from the root of your crate. But there is no `math` module as direct child of the root module, hence the error.

Comment: I was using 1.16. But thanks for the tip, it seems to work now!